# Extract/Save Element's Text AND Images with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Working with Windows, Python 3 and Selenium/Chromedriver, I'm trying to figure out a way to save an element's data (text AND images) to an offline file for later viewing. Things I've tried:

**1. Save page source to .html file**

```
    page_source = driver.page_source
    with open("page.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(page_source)
```

Problem with this is, it only saves the text of the page, not the images, just empty image placeholders are rendered on the saved page, not the actual images.

**2. Take screenshots of the entire page**

```
    page_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollWidth')
    page_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    driver.set_window_size(page_width, page_height)
    driver.save_screenshot("page.png")
```

Problem here is, even though I'm defining the entire page height/width, only the visible section of the page is screenshot'd, not the entire page worth of data, so scrolling would need to be incorporated.

**3. Use a "select all" type logic taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663587/how-to-select-copy-and-paste-everything-within-an-element-using-selenium-webdri)**

This is kind of a hacky workaround, but could work, but kind of looking for a better solution.

**4. Make use of pressing CTRL + S to save the page and assets for offline viewing**

This was ok, but it downloads a bunch of stuff into a separate folder that is needed to render the entire page, which I don't think is necessary as I only want the stuff from one element on the page. Plus I'll be downloading several pages and I don't want separate folders of stuff for each page either.

So I'm wondering if there's a better way to save the text AND images of a page element, preferably to a html, docx, or pdf file type? I've seen various solutions on SO, but haven't found one that can do this so looking for some direction/steer me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar code to take a screenshot of the entire page, but it works only in headless mode, so try in headless and let me know. But I don't understand, you want to save all the page or just an element of the page? For example, all this page or only the element `div.question`?

Comment: Hmm. Well I didn't try headless mode as there's a 2FA that I need to manually enter onto the screen which sucks, but you're right, that code WAS run in headless mode so I'm sure it would work. I don't really care if it's the entire page or just the element. Preferably just the element, as I don't need all the top menu items, etc. from the page. I guess I can just make option 3 above work for now, but was just wondering if there was a better option?

Comment: I don't know if I got it right, because it is easy to get text and screen of an element, I'll post it in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a CTRL + A, CTRL + C to copy all the text and images from the entire page. I then use win32clipboard to access the data from within the clipboard, and export it to a docx file. Kind of hacky, and doesn't get just the content from the element only, but it works for my purposes. Maybe someone will have a better solution in the future.

```
a = ActionChains(driver)
a.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
sleep(1)
a.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('c').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

current_books_pages_list = []
while True:
    try:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        current_books_pages_list.append(data)
        print("Woohoo!")
        break
    except:
        print("Clipboard access denied error, trying again...")
        sleep(1)
        continue

with open("books/" + str(book_name_string) + ".docx", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for page_data in current_books_pages_list:
        file.write(page_data)
        file.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes a screenshot of the element `#mp-topbanner` and print the text it contains

```
driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mp-topbanner')
element.screenshot('screen.png')
print(element.text)
```

output

```
Welcome to Wikipedia,
the free encyclopedia that anyone can edit.
6,498,975 articles in English
```

Comment: I think to help understand the problem a bit better, try changing the element to `#mp-upper` instead of `#mp-topbanner`. This will attempt to get the main table body. You'll see how the screenshot only gets the visible section of the page, and yes it does get the text, but my question is, how can I save all the text and images in an element to an offline file for later viewing. Like, try to copy and paste the `#mp-upper` element's data into a separate .html or .pdf file, that includes the images and the text in one document, following the directions laid out in the question.